# Predis : ERR unknown command 'EVAL' at Client.php:370

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, redis, predis

I am using Laravel 5.5  and Redis client 3.2.6 and get the following error:

> ERR unknown command 'EVAL' {"exception":"[object]
>   (Predis\Response\ServerException(code: 0): ERR unknown command
>   'EVAL' at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\munition\vendor\predis\predis\src\Client.php:370)

Comment: check your php.ini may be eval is disable as dangerous func

Comment: if i enable it , will it not result in error any more ? i.e assert.quiet_eval = 1

Comment: may be it will help

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same issue using redis version 2.4.5. Upgrading it to version 3.0.504 from [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftArchive/redis/releases) solved the problem for me.